# High CPU Load with Display Link Docks -> alternatives

Tags: 20.04, displaylink, docking

Is there any docking station that supports 2 external screens which does not use the DisplayLink chipset?

On different laptops we have the problem of very high CPU load with DisplayLink drivers and look for any alternative.